# Chaining dataframe sort in pandas produces unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas

This is the dataframe `activity`:

```
| player_id | device_id | event_date | games_played |
| --------- | --------- | ---------- | ------------ |
| 1         | 2         | 2016-03-01 | 5            |
| 1         | 2         | 2016-05-02 | 1            |
| 1         | 3         | 2015-06-25 | 2            |
| 3         | 1         | 2016-03-02 | 10           |
| 3         | 4         | 2016-02-03 | 15           |
```

Running

```
activity.sort_values('event_date').assign(\
        games_played_so_far = activity.groupby('player_id')\
        .games_played.cumsum())[['player_id', 'event_date', 'games_played_so_far']]
```

produces

```
| player_id | event_date | games_played_so_far |
| --------- | ---------- | ------------------- |
| 1         | 2015-06-25 | 8                   |
| 3         | 2016-02-03 | 25                  |
| 1         | 2016-03-01 | 5                   |
| 3         | 2016-03-02 | 10                  |
| 1         | 2016-05-02 | 6                   |
```

whereas doing the sorting separately

```
activity.sort_values('event_date', inplace = True)
activity.assign(games_played_so_far = activity.groupby('player_id')\
        .games_played.cumsum())[['player_id', 'event_date', 'games_played_so_far']]
```

produces

```
| player_id | event_date | games_played_so_far |
| --------- | ---------- | ------------------- |
| 1         | 2015-06-25 | 2                   |
| 1         | 2016-03-01 | 7                   |
| 1         | 2016-05-02 | 8                   |
| 3         | 2016-02-03 | 15                  |
| 3         | 2016-03-02 | 25                  |
```

Why?

I noticed that this unexpected behaviour occurs irregularly - for many dataframes the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `.assign(games_played_so_far = activity.groupby('player_id').games_played.cumsum())`, you're working on the original non-sorted DataFrame.

You can use a callable in [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to ensure accessing the **current** state of the DataFrame:

```
out = (activity.sort_values('event_date')
       # with a callable, we use the current (sorted) state of the DataFrame
       .assign(games_played_so_far = lambda d: d.groupby('player_id').games_played.cumsum())
      [['player_id', 'event_date', 'games_played_so_far']]
      )
```

Output:

```
   player_id  event_date  games_played_so_far
2          1  2015-06-25                    2
4          3  2016-02-03                   15
0          1  2016-03-01                    7
3          3  2016-03-02                   25
1          1  2016-05-02                    8
```

To better  understand what's going on, consider this other example. We set up a DataFrame, multiply by 10 and assign columns referencing the original or current DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3]})

out = (df.mul(10)  # update since original
         .assign(col2=df['col1'],          # referencing original
                 col3=lambda d: d['col1']) # referencing current
      )

   col1  col2  col3
0    10     1    10
1    20     2    20
2    30     3    30
```

Only the callable (`lambda`) version reflects the **current** state of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Because need `lambda` function if need processing output of chained functions in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), here sorted `activity` DataFrame:

```
(activity.sort_values('event_date')
      .assign(games_played_so_far = lambda x: x.groupby('player_id').games_played.cumsum())
           [['player_id', 'event_date', 'games_played_so_far']])
```

If omit `lambda` pandas use original `activity` DataFrame, here not sorted.

```
(activity.sort_values('event_date')
        .assign(games_played_so_far = activity.groupby('player_id').games_played.cumsum())
            [['player_id', 'event_date', 'games_played_so_far']])
```